# Unable to run ASP.NET web application in MEDIUM trust level

Tags: iis, asp.net

I developed an Web Application and published it on my Shared Hosting. After that I am receiving following error-

[image]

To resolve it, I contacted my hosting providers and they told me to set my application to run in Medium Trust and to contact with my developer (that is me this case :P).

Now, I added `<trust level="Medium" />` in my web.config file and it is not even running on my local machine now.

After many research I thought to test this feature with brand new project-

1. Created a brand new ASP.NET MVC project and set trust level to Medium. (No success)
2. Created another project as empty. Added a default.aspx page and set the trust level to Medium (No success again).

Now I am unsure how to resolve this.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you find the answer? I have the same problem as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974750/system-security-permissions-fileiopermission-error-when-trying-to-upload-a-file

Answer (score 0):

MVC5 does not support medium trust. Either use MVC4 or change trust level to full. There are several posts related to this issue.